# Android datepicker ondateSetListener executed twice

Tags: android

Every time my code launch the callback, date is picked (and inserted in database) twice.

Of course I don't need this beahviour. Note that error is in Bluestack Emulator (android 4.3), Galaxy Ace rooted with Cyanogenmod 4.4 but not in my Samsung s3 (android 4.3)

Thank you

```
private void setFab(){
        // BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton newEventButton = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.set_new_event);
        newEventButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), datePickerListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                /*dialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", dialog);
                dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"OK",dialog.onDateChanged(DatePicker view););*/
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                              int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            String stringYear = Integer.toString(selectedYear);

            selectedMonth = selectedMonth+1;

            String stringMonth = Integer.toString(selectedMonth);

            if (stringMonth.length()==1){
                stringMonth = "0"+stringMonth;
            }

            String stringDay = Integer.toString(selectedDay);

            if (stringDay.length()==1){
                stringDay = "0"+stringDay;
            }

            String date = stringYear+"-"+stringMonth+"-"+stringDay+" 00:00:00";
            setEvent(date);
            //last_event = getLastEvent();
            setDashboard();

        }
    };
```